# How can I achieve Session Replication using PHP/Apache

Tags: php, session, state

Is there a way to store/manage PHP sessions in a similar way that the IIS (Session State Service) ?

I want to have multiple front end web servers for an multi domain e-commerce platform and manage the sessions centrally. The idea being that is a server goes down users with cart contents will not have to start a new session when they are shifted to a another web server.

I know cookies and URL parameters could do it to a point but that's not answering the question.

Comment: I think in this case the best idea would instead to save the session information in the database instead of the file system (I could be wrong though).

Comment: If you are looking for session replication this may help http://serverfault.com/questions/164350/can-a-pool-of-memcache-daemons-be-used-to-share-sessions-more-efficiently

Comment: Thanks for the link, just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can register a [`SessionHandlerInterface`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) which is backed by a shared database (e.g. MySQL Cluster).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this because they are moving to Amazon Web Services, there are two options/alternatives:

1. Use the [DynamoDB session handler](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-dynamodb-session-handler.html) from the AWS SDK for PHP. This essentially has the same effect as session replication. However, there are monetary costs from DynamoDB, especially if you need locking.
2. Use [session stickiness](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_StickySessions.html) in the load balancer. This is simpler to set up, and free, but is probably not quite as scalable, as requests from old sessions can't just be sent on to newly started servers.

The most scalable option is of course to get rid of server-side sessions, but that is not always easy without huge changes in backends and frontends, and in some cases not even desirable because of other considerations.

Comment: Session stickiness doesn't help OP.